# ProgressBar when AsyncTask.get() is called

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I wrote this little application that take some datas from a web service and put them in a custom ListView:

**SOAP CALL**

```
public String getVoy(String voy) {
    String SOAP_ACTION = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    String METHOD_NAME = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    String NAMESPACE = "urn:DefaultNamespace";
    String URL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.nsf/xxxxxxx?wsdl";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("VOY", voy);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        final SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        rt = (result != null) ? result.getProperty(0).toString() : "Nessuna risposta 1";

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // Invio il webservice

    return rt;
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
 private class LineCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String text = WebService.getInstance().getVoy(params[0]);

        return text;
    }
}
```

**Call the AsyncTask and get the datas**

```
LineCall line = new LineCall();
    line.execute(voy);

    try {
        **string** = line.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then I take the **string** variable, split my datas and put them in the custom list...

It works very well but the problem is that **is very slow** so I tried to create a ProgressDialog but there are some problems...

If I put it in the previous activity:

```
 Button partenze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.partenze);
    partenze.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StartDeapartures call = new StartDeapartures();
            call.execute();

        }
    });
}
private class StartDeapartures extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading..");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Partenze.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

The progress image don't move and it seems freezed and if i put it in the LineCall asyncTask the ProgressDialog is not showed...

I found in google that this is dued to string = line.get(); that takes a long time to run...

So how can i put a ProgressDialog when get() is working ?

Comment: no need to use **string** = line.get(); line just use onPostExecute for getting response from server and then show in ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `AsyncTask.get()`, it will block the main thread until the `doInBackground` completes. So, you should not call `AsyncTask.get()`, instead you should handle the result and do UI operations in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` method. This is the designed behaviour of `AsyncTask`.

In your StartDeapartures asynctask, why do you start an activity in doInBackground? What is the point of using an AsyncTask for starting an activity?